# Finding equilibrium temperature in a rod with a Robin boundary condition.

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

> Determine the equilibrium temperature distribution for a 1D rod with constant thermal properties with following source and boundary conditions  $$Q=0,u(0)=T,\frac{\partial u(L)}{\partial x}+u(L)=0$$

My work thus far: First in equilibrium $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=0$ so we find the equilibrium temperature by integrating $u''(x)=0$ twice, obtaining $u_{eq}(x)=c_1x+c_2$.

My approach is to apply the first boundary condition $u(0)=T$, we get $c_2=T$. My confusion then comes in applying the second boundary condition.
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u(L)}{\partial x}+u(L)&=0\\
c_1+c_1(L)+T&=0\\
c_1&=\frac{-T}{1+L}\\
\end{align}
Therefore $u_{eq}=\frac{-T}{1+L}x+T$.

Is this the correct approach?

**Note** I know that there are a lot of similar problems already posted but I have seen none with a [Robin boundary condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_boundary_condition)

Comment: applying the first boundary condition $u(0) = T$ should give $c_2 = T,$ not $c_2 = 0,$ right?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen yes let me correct that.

Comment: Looks right. (Although you should edit out the part about both coefficients being zero.)

Comment: It looks correct.